# Почему белка — белка?

Tags: этимология

Почему она называется белка, если сама никогда не бывает белой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложное последовательное преобразование слов. Изначально "отблеск, огонь" - рыжая же, потом приплелось "отливающий белым", потом получилась белка.

Кстати зимой она вполне себе светлая, хоть и не белоснежная, в отличие от куньих.

Answer (score 0):

*Белый* в старину значило *прозрачный, невидимый*: белый свет, сказка про белого бычка.

Видимо, векшу прозвали белкой за быстроту движений. Зверёк-призрак.))))

Answer (score 0):

пузо у нее белое, оттого и белка.